# Draw over mutliple subfigures after resizebox

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, resize, remember

I have several TikZ pictures of different sizes, and I need to use the `resizebox` function to convert them to the same size and put them into a single figure by `subfigure`. I also want to add some edges between these subfigures.

The image I expect to get is as follows:

[image]

Here is my current approach.

I use `\tikz[remember picture] \node () {...};` as mentioned in [Draw over mutliple subfigures [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245794/254188). The resulting picture is like:

[image]

Then I add the `resizebox` function, but the result is not as expected. It seems that the original positions of the nodes are remembered instead of the resized ones.

[image]

How to properly draw over multiple subfigures after `resizebox`? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}  % for subfigure
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\tikz[remember picture] \node[draw, dashed] (9) {\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,9} {\node[draw] (9-\i) at (\i, \i) {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}}};
\caption{9 boxes}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\tikz[remember picture] \node[draw, dashed] (6) {\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,6} {\node[draw] (6-\i) at (-\i,\i) {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}}};
\caption{6 boxes}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\tikz[remember picture] \node[draw, dashed] (3) {\resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {\node[draw] (3-\i) at (\i,\i) {\i};}
\end{tikzpicture}}};
\caption{3 boxes}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw (9-9.north east) -- (6.north west);
    \draw (9-9.south east) -- (6.south west);
    \draw (6-3.north east) -- (3.north west);
    \draw (6-3.south east) -- (3.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ doesn't seem to know anything about the outer `\resizebox` and uses the original placement. Do you want to actually resize your individual figures or do you just want to reduce the distance between nodes? Maybe, the `spy` library is a better approach to your diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting TikZ pictures is a dangerous thing. Let's try to avoid this.

For this, I'm using the experimental `ext.scalepicture` library from my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) together with `transform shape`. Instead of a picture inside a node, we will just `fit` a dashed node around the bounding box at the end of the picture.

I'm sure with a bunch of math we could compute the appropriate scaling but the library does it by remembering the last picture size via the AUX file.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}  % for subfigure
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.scalepicture, fit}
\newcommand*\tikznnodes[2][]{%
  \tikz[
    picture width=.9\linewidth, transform shape, remember picture,
    execute at end picture={%
      \node[draw,dashed,outer sep=+0pt,
        fit=(current bounding box)](#2){};},#1]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,#2}
      \node[draw] (#2-\i) at (\i, \i) {\i};}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering \tikznnodes{9} \caption{9 boxes}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering \tikznnodes{6} \caption{6 boxes}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering \tikznnodes{3} \caption{3 boxes}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]
  \foreach \A/\B in {9-9/6, 6-3/3}
    \draw (\A.north east) -- (\B.north west)
          (\A.south east) -- (\B.south west);
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a `\pic` for the 'squares' that, like all `\pics`, is scalable. Then it creates a macro for the subfigures, only to reduce code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}  % only tosee the page layout
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset
{% pic that draws a square with #1 nodes (starting from 0)
 % if #1>0 draws them raising form left to right
 % if #1<0 draws them raising form right to left
   pics/my square/.style={
      code={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myabs{abs(#1)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\mysign{#1/\myabs}
        \begin{scope}[x=\mysign cm,shift={(0.5*\mysign-0.5,0)}]
          \draw[dashed] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
          \foreach\i in {0,...,\myabs}
            \node[draw,dashed,inner sep=0,minimum size=3mm] (-\i) at ({(\i+0.5)/(1+\myabs)},{(\i+0.5)/(1+\myabs)}) {$\i$};
        \end{scope}
        \coordinate (-sw) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (-se) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (-ne) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (-nw) at (0,1);
    }},
}

% A macro that draws the subfigures using the \pic (scaled)
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxes}{mm}
{%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \tikz\pic[dashed,scale=\mysize] (#1) {my square=#2};
    \caption{\pgfmathparse{int(abs(#2))}\pgfmathresult{} boxes}
  \end{subfigure}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\pgfmathsetmacro\mysize{0.3*0.0351459804*\textwidth} % converts 0.3\textwidth to cm
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\boxes{a}{9}%
\hfill
\boxes{b}{-6}%
\hfill
\boxes{c}{3}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,red]
  \draw (b-nw) -- (a-9) -- (b-sw);
  \draw (c-nw) -- (b-3) -- (c-sw);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]